# Using python to check if two matrices are similar

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

I've long done this problem by hand, or by using other algebraic techniques, but am facing ever more problems where the algebraic techniques are failing and I'm falling back on by hand computations which seem tailor made for python (namely, boring, repetitive and lengthy tasks that could be automated). I was therefore wondering if there are any well-known ways to check similarity of matrices using python? By this I mean the following. Suppose we have two square matrices X, Y over a ring (let's say Z for ease). We say these two matrices are similar if we can find an invertible matrix P such that P^{-1}XP = Y.

If there isn't then I suppose I could write a script for this but right now wouldn't know where to start. I have tried for some small 2x2 matrices but these seem computationally very expensive and work don't seem suitable for larger matrices. Any suggestions?

What I expect to happen is for a programme to take two matrices and input and then check whether an invertible matrix $P$ exists such that $XP=PY$. Only tried making it work for small 2x2 cases so far and not getting very far.